# How can a Knockout JS component viewmodel function be used as a callback?

Tags: knockout.js

According to Knockout Documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#component-lifecycle), a component viewModel is only instantiated "on demand", considered it is declared such as:

```html
<div data-bind='component: {
    name: componentNameObservable,
    params: { mode: "detailed-list", items: productsList }
}'></div>
```

Consider the scenario of a Single Page Application with a routing mechanism such as SammyJS, Crossroads.js, or any other.

When a route change request matches a route pattern, it is usual to make the routing library handler for the route matched event to set a new value for componentNameObservable. This will trigger the injection of a new component into the bound element.
On top of that, also inside this route matched handler, let's say I want to execute a function declared inside the component viewModel being bound, to refresh/setup view model data, responding to route changed event. How would that be possible?
Since the component viewModel instantiation in these cases is controlled by Knockout's internal component binding mechanism, I cannot access its functions so that I could reference them as callbacks to be executed.
If it were possible, I would pass a component viewModel function as a callback parameter to the routing library route matched handler, then execute the callback function, all would be nice... But doesn't seem to work that way...

I am registering the component using CommonJS to work with Browserify, such as described here

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#note-integrating-with-browserify

In this case, the module.exports on the component view model has to expose its entire non-instantiated constructor function, so that whatever require('myViewModel') gets translated into, gets the view model to be correctly "newed up" upon binding to the element.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"[..] make the routing library handler for the route matched event to set a new value for componentNameObservable."* is mutually exclusive with:
*"[..] execute a function declared inside the component viewModel being bound, [..] responding to route changed event"*. because your component is torn down every time the route changes. So you can only ever react to route change twice: in constructor function (setup), or before component teardown, in the [dispose callback](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#disposal-and-memory-management). At least, that is, with this setup.

Comment: You are right, @Tyblitz, the case is that I failed to elaborate further on my setup for this case. In fact, in the spa setup I am talking about, the setter for a new value for componentNameObservable occurs in a different knockout component as opposed to the component I wish to execute a function inside its viewModel.

Comment: On the same html, there is one component handling the navigation (the one that sets componentNameObservable) and a another container tag with knockout's component binding, such as the snippet shown on the beginning of the question. Based on what the navigation component turns the componentNameObservable into, any number of different other components get injected one at a time into the container (in this case a div) with the component binding.

Comment: @Tyblitz, when you say _"[..] react to route change [..]"_  _"[..] in constructor function (setup) [..] "_, it is then an "indirect" reaction to route change, because it is not the route change that got the viewModel constructor function to fire directly, but the fact that knockout injected a new component into the container, causing its view model to be instantiated... It is an interesting path to follow though.... To get the same job done as the callback function I first asked... I'm digging further into this possibility...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've successfully used this technique ([example](https://github.com/webketje/GS-Custom-Settings/blob/master/src/custom_settings/js/modules/tabs-manage.js)) before (declaring an `init` and `dispose` function on the prototype). If you then pass the constructor the `params` it requires to do its setup work, your constructor *becomes* your callback (amongst others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> let's say I want to execute a function declared inside the component viewModel being bound, to refresh/setup view model data, responding to route changed event. How would that be possible?

In the [component registration documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html) you have 4 different options to provide the view model:

- 1st: A constructor function
- 2nd: A shared object instance
- 3rd: A createViewModel factory function
- 4th: An AMD module whose value describes a viewmodel

In fact, the 4th option is using an AMD module to return one of the other 3 options. So there are only 3 possible options, with or without using `require`.

If your SPA will only use a single instance of your component, you can use the second solution: create a viewmodel, store it in a variable which is always in scope (for example in global scope or inside a module), and register the component to use it. In this way, when the component is instanced by the routing event, you can access the viewmodel through the variable to invoke the desired functionality.

If your SPA can have several different instances of your component, or you simply don't want to use the previous solution, you must use the 1st or 3rd option (regarding this question, it doesn't matter which one). In this case you can pass a callback function to your component, which will be available in the constructor (1st option) or factory method (3rd option) parameters. The constructor (or factory) can invoke this callback to expose its functionality. You can implement something like this, but not necessarily exactly like this:

In the main scope of your application

```
// Here you'll store the component APIs to access them:
var childrenComponentsApi = {};
// This will be passed as a callback, so that the child component
// can register the API
var registerChildComponentApi = function(api) {
    childrenComponentsApi.componentX = api;
};
```

*NOTE: it's important to have an object where the functionality can be registered so that you don't lose the reference*

In the view:

```
<div data-bind='component: {
  name: 'componentX',
  params: { registerApi: registerChildComponentApi, /*other params*/ }
}'></div>
```

In the components view model constructor (or factory) body:

```
params.registerApi({ // The callback is available in thereceived params
   func1: func1,  // register the desired functions
   func2: func2});
```

Later on, in the main scope, you can access the component's functionality like this:

childrenComponentsApi.componentX.fun1(/* params */);

This is not exactly working code, but I hope it gives you an idea on how to implement what you need.

This solution works perfectly if the API isn't invoked inmediately. I used this implementation when the functionality will be invoked ny a user's action, so that I'm sure that the component is already instanced.

But, in your case, the component creation is asynchronous, so you have to modify the implementation. There are at least two possible ways:

1) the easier one is to change the `registerApi` implementation and use it to cal the initialization. Something like this:

In the viewmodels constructor:

```
params.registerApi({
   init: init,    // initialization function
   func1: func1,  // other exposed functionality
   func2: func2});
```

In the main scope:

```
var registerChildComponentApi = function(api) {
    childrenComponentsApi.componentX = api;
    childrenComponentsApi.componentx.init(/* params*/)
}
```

In this implementacion `init` is called after the callback has been run by the client component, so you can be sure the component is available.

2) a more complex solution involves using promises. If your component needs to do asynchronous operations to get ready (for example doing AJAX calls), you can make it return a promise besides all the exposed API, so that the component  solves the promise when it's really ready, and the main scope runs the API functionality only when the promise has been solved. Something like this:

In the view model constructor:

```
params.registerApi({
   ready: ready,  // promise created and solved by the component
   func1: func1,  // exposed functionality
   func2: func2});
```

In the main scope:

```
var registerChildComponentApi = function(api) {
    childrenComponentsApi.componentX = api;
}
childrenComponentsApi.componentx.ready().then(
   childrenComponentsApi.componentx.func1;
);
```

These are some implementation samples, but there can be many variations on them.  For example, if you only need to run the `init` function of the component viewmodel, you can supply a parameter like `provideInit` to the component, and run it in the consturctor by pasing the component's `init`. Something like this:

```
<div data-bind='component: {
  name: 'componentX',
  params: { provideInit: provideInit, /*other params*/ }
}'></div>

var proviedInit: function(init) {
   init(/* params */);
};
```

And don't forget that it's also possible to initialize the component's viewmodel by passing all the necessary parameters to the constructor.Or even by passing observables as parameters and modifying them from the main scope.

The last best advice I can give you is that you standardize and document correctly the `registerApi` functonality, so that all the components are implemented and used in the same way.

As I told in the beginning, any of these solutions can be implemented directly, or by using AMD modules. I.e. you can register the component providing the view model constructor directly (1st option), or defining the constructor as an AMD module and using the 4th option.

Comment: Excellent, @JotaBe, I got it working exactly as intended. My SPA, for this case, requires only a single instance of the component (components = pages for my SPA). I setup a shared viewmodel module, exporting instances of each of my pages viewModels. Those always in scope, whenever they are required. I used these shared viewModel objects to then register components providing the viewmodel as 2nd option: A shared object instance. I now have access to everything exposed for these viewModels, can use their functions as callbacks, can set observables directly, really helpful.

Comment: what really gave me the insight was your statement: _the 4th option is using an AMD module to return one of the other 3 options. So there are only 3 possible options, with or without using require_. This was the game changer, documentation did not lead me to this conclusion.

Comment: Another thing, @JotaBe, I'm actually using CommonJS, not AMD, a possibility stated in documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#note-integrating-with-browserify). Notice that this link explicitly states: _Note that the following *only* works with Browserify - not with require.js, since it relies on require() returning synchronously_.  Does this change what you said: _But, in your case, the component creation is asynchronous, so you have to modify the implementation._ ?

Comment: So far, it is adequate for me to use single instances for my page components, but surely enough I'll be using multiple instances of other components inside these pages. I'll then get back to all the accurate information you suggested regarding this possibility too... Thanks @JotaBe!